# ant task to split the given strings

Tags: ant

I need to split the strings from the given url and that to be stored in a property.

Eg: Url: projectname/qa/projectid/version
    Properties need to be store:
         Name=projectname
         Mode=qa
         Id=projectid
         Version=version

Comment: split works with regexp, see my edit.. also Ant Flaka split takes regexp.

Answer (score 8):

Use builtin javascript engine (JDK >= 1.6.06) and [ant script task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) :

```
<project>

<property name="url" value="projectname/qa/projectid/version"/>

 <script language="javascript">
  arr = project.getProperty('url').split('/');
  project.setProperty('Name', arr[0]);
  project.setProperty('Mode', arr[1]);
  project.setProperty('Id', arr[2]);
  project.setProperty('Version', arr[3]);
 </script>

 <echo>
  $${Name}    => ${Name}
  $${Mode}    => ${Mode}
  $${Id}      => ${Id}
  $${Version} => ${Version}
 </echo>

</project>
```

output :

```
[echo]   ${Name}    => projectname
[echo]   ${Mode}    => qa
[echo]   ${Id}      => projectid
[echo]   ${Version} => version
```

Wrap it up in a [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) or [scriptdef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html) for reuse (equivalent to writing a new ant task).
If you prefer using some ant addon instead of ant script task see [Ant Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) which has several possibilities for string manipulation, see [manual](http://workbench.haefelinger.it/flaka/download/manual/flaka-1.2.2.html) and [examples](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/wiki/FlakaExamples).

-- EDIT --
split works with regexp, f.e. :

```
<project>
<property name="url" value="Chico.Harpo.Groucho.Gummo.Zeppo"/>

 <script language="javascript">
 <![CDATA[

  // won't work because special meaning of '.' as wildcard
  // arr = project.getProperty('url').split('.');
  // so either use
  // masking as character class '[.]' or '\\.'
  arr = project.getProperty('url').split('[.]'); 
   for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
   {
     print(arr[i]);
   }
 ]]>
 </script>

</project>
```

Comment: Thank you Rebse, i have tried it, its working by using java script. Is there any probability that to make it with using regular expression?

Comment: My god. Mixing Ant and Javascript. What an amazing combination of parts. Dr. Frankenstein would be proud.   (But, thank you!)

Answer (score 4):

Just to show an alternative to Rebse's `script` approach, here is a more long-winded way with regular expression. You could extract each property with a block like this:

```
<property name="url" value="projectname/qa/projectid/version"/>

<loadresource property="Name">
  <string value="${url}"/>
  <filterchain>
    <tokenfilter>
      <replaceregex pattern="(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)" replace="\1"/>
    </tokenfilter>
  </filterchain>
</loadresource>
<echo message="Name: ${Name}"/>
```

To answer your question from the comments, here is an example of how you could use that approach to extract the pieces you require. I didn't say it was pretty...

```
<target name="test">
    <property name="url" value="http://svn.abc.com/builds/abcd/qa/FACC790C-1480-49F7-80F6-B91B07E52DA9/v1.0.1/r5532/"/>

    <echo message="url: ${url}"/>

    <loadresource property="a">
      <string value="${url}"/>
      <filterchain>
        <tokenfilter>
          <replaceregex pattern="http://([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(?:[^/]+)/([^/]+)/v([^/]+)/r([^/]+)/" replace="\1"/>
        </tokenfilter>
      </filterchain>
    </loadresource>
    <echo message="a: ${a}"/>

    <loadresource property="b">
      <string value="${url}"/>
      <filterchain>
        <tokenfilter>
          <replaceregex pattern="http://([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(?:[^/]+)/([^/]+)/v([^/]+)/r([^/]+)/" replace="\2"/>
        </tokenfilter>
      </filterchain>
    </loadresource>
    <echo message="b: ${b}"/>

   <loadresource property="c">
      <string value="${url}"/>
      <filterchain>
        <tokenfilter>
          <replaceregex pattern="http://([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(?:[^/]+)/([^/]+)/v([^/]+)/r([^/]+)/" replace="\3"/>
        </tokenfilter>
      </filterchain>
    </loadresource>
    <echo message="c: ${c}"/>

   <loadresource property="d">
      <string value="${url}"/>
      <filterchain>
        <tokenfilter>
          <replaceregex pattern="http://([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(?:[^/]+)/([^/]+)/v([^/]+)/r([^/]+)/" replace="\4"/>
        </tokenfilter>
      </filterchain>
    </loadresource>
    <echo message="d: ${d}"/>

   <loadresource property="e">
      <string value="${url}"/>
      <filterchain>
        <tokenfilter>
          <replaceregex pattern="http://([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(?:[^/]+)/([^/]+)/v([^/]+)/r([^/]+)/" replace="\5"/>
        </tokenfilter>
      </filterchain>
    </loadresource>
    <echo message="e: ${e}"/>

   <loadresource property="f">
      <string value="${url}"/>
      <filterchain>
        <tokenfilter>
          <replaceregex pattern="http://([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(?:[^/]+)/([^/]+)/v([^/]+)/r([^/]+)/" replace="\6"/>
        </tokenfilter>
      </filterchain>
    </loadresource>
    <echo message="f: ${f}"/>
</target>
```

Output:

```
test:
     [echo] url: http://svn.abc.com/builds/abcd/qa/FACC790C-1480-49F7-80F6-B91B07E52DA9/v1.0.1/r5532/
     [echo] a: svn.abc.com
     [echo] b: builds
     [echo] c: abcd
     [echo] d: FACC790C-1480-49F7-80F6-B91B07E52DA9
     [echo] e: 1.0.1
     [echo] f: 5532
```

So in summary, reusing the same pattern each time, but selecting a different group (1-4). The pattern uses 6 capturing and 1 non-capturing group (for the /qa/ part). Lots of other ways you could do that.

Comment: Script task is also core Ant. When using builtin javascript engine no addon jars needed.

Comment: The above code works fine, but in my case i would like to know the regular expression equivalent for the below mentioned url: 

http://svn.abc.com/builds/abcd/qa/FACC790C-1480-49F7-80F6-B91B07E52DA9/v1.0.1/r5532/
I need to retrieve the values as, 
a=http://svn.abc.com
b=builds
c=abcd
d=FACC790C-1480-49F7-80F6-B91B07E52DA9
e=1.0.1
f=5532

Any small piece of help would be great.